# Can't link two methods C#

Tags: c#, task

I have code:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace TimeTress
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var timelineCSV = GetListOfStringsFromTextFile("../../../../timeline.csv");
            var peopleCSV = GetListOfStringsFromTextFile("../../../../people.csv");

            var timeline = ReadData(timelineCSV);
            var people = ReadData(peopleCSV);
        }
        static string GetNameOfPeoples(string[][] people)
        {
            var nowDate = DateTime.Now;
            var countYears = 20;
            if ((DateTime.IsLeapYear(yearBirthday)) && (bitrthdayElement.Year - nowDate.Year) <= countYears) return namePeople;
        }
        static (string, int, DateTime) GetNamePeoplesAndYears(string[][] people)
        {
            foreach (var elements in people)
            {
                DateTime bitrthdayElement = ParseDate(elements[2]);
                var yearBirthday = bitrthdayElement.Year;
                var namePeople = elements[1];
            }
            return (namePeople, yearBirthday, birthdayElement);
        }
        static string[] GetListOfStringsFromTextFile(string filePath)
        {
            string[] stringArray;

            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                stringArray = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
            }
            else
            {
                stringArray = new string[0];
            }

            return stringArray;
        }
        static void OutputString(string[] getString)
        {
            foreach (var lines in getString)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(lines);
            }
        }

        static string[][] ReadData(string[] array)
        {
            string[][] splitData = new string[array.Length][];
            for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                var line = array[i];
                string[] parts = line.Split(";");
                splitData[i] = parts;
            }

            return splitData;
        }
        static DateTime ParseDate(string value)
        {
            DateTime date;
            if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
            {
                if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "yyyy-mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
                {
                    if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "yyyy-mm-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
                    {
                        throw new Exception("WRONG FORMAT");
                    }
                }
            }

            return date;
        }

    }
}
```

In GetListOfStringsFromTextFile i get string[].
In ReadData i get a string[][].

The whole program works correctly, the problem is in two methods.

GetNamePeoplesAndYears which takes values from a file like {1; name; date} and returns three values name, year of birth and full date of birth

The second method GetNameOfPeoples checks the year of birth for leap years and then checks if the person is under 20 years old

Comment: A standard `IsLeapYear` algorithm: Take the year (`int y`). Test if `y%400` is zero, if so, return is a leap year, if not, test if `y%100` is zero, if yes, return is not a leap year. Then test if `y%4` is zero, if yes, then return is a leap year, otherwise, return is not a leap year

Comment: I have a function IsLeapYear which check on leap year in method GetNameOfPeoples

Comment: `bool IsLeapYear(int year) => year % 400 == 0 || (year % 4 == 0 ^ year % 100 == 0);`

Comment: we can find leap year by using this condition as Flydog57 mentioned.   if (((Year % 4 == 0) && (Year % 100 != 0)) || (Year % 400 == 0)){ //leap year  }

Comment: Or `bool IsLeapYear(int year) => new DateTime(year, 2, 28).AddDays(1.5).Month == 2;`. Although, this is fragile with some numbers for year.

Comment: Your "question" is _"Method for determining whether a leap year C#"_, you show a call to an `IsYeapYear` function, but no implementation. I quite naturally assumed that you wanted what you asked. What do you want?

Comment: but the problem is that I cannot link the two methods.  The first, which calculates returns the name of people, year of birth and full date of birth, and the second already checks the conditions and they do not work together

Comment: @IlyaKvashnin which methods do you want to link? and what is the expected result if you achieve it?

Comment: I resist the urge to write something that complex in a single line. The code gen for `bool IsLeapYear(int year) => year % 400 == 0 || (year % 4 == 0 ^ year % 100 == 0);` is probably exactly the same as for my wordy version (I just make explicit the short-circuiting behavior that's in the one-line version). The difference is that I can use step-by-step debugging to check my version out. If there's a bug in the one-line version, it's much less fun. Readability and debuggability are always two of my goals

Comment: @AmalPs I want link GetNamePeoplesAndYears and GetNameOfPeoples the rest works quite correctly. I need the first method to accept values from a file, and the second to check them for a leap condition and age less than 20

Comment: @IlyaKvashnin I've added an answer. If it doesn't solve your problem let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to link the two methods GetNamePeoplesAndYears and GetNameOfPeoples and return the values you may need to change the parameter passing to the GetNameOfPeoples function. By passing the respective values or a class having the needed data can solve your issue. For example:

```
 var result =  GetNamePeoplesAndYears(people);
 GetNameOfPeoples(result.Item1, result.Item2, result.Item3);


      static string GetNameOfPeoples(string namePeople, int yearBirthday, DateTime bitrthdayElement )
        {
            var nowDate = DateTime.Now;
            var countYears = 20;
            if ((DateTime.IsLeapYear(yearBirthday)) && (bitrthdayElement.Year - nowDate.Year) <= countYears) 
                return namePeople;
             return String.Empty; // if your data doesn't met the condion it needs to return some string. So add needful 

            }
```

by using a class you can do the same. then the parameter will be the object of that class.
Hope it will help you to solve this issue.

Edit: If you want the string[][] as input parameter and return all the names and age you can try this

```
static List<propleData> NamePeoples(string[][] people) {
            
        var listPeople = new List<propleData> { };
        foreach (var elements in people) 
        {
            var item = new propleData();
           
            item.names = elements[1];
            item.years = ParseDate(elements[2]).Year;
            listPeople.Add(item);
        }
        return listPeople;
   
}
//create a class or you can use dictionary instead of list
        public class propleData
        {
            public string names { get; set; }
            public int years { get; set; }


        }
```

you can retrieve the data from the list by iterating the list. I'll give an example.

```
var namePeople = NamePeoples(people);
            string name = string.Empty;
            int year = 0;
            foreach (propleData propleData in namePeople)
            {
                name = propleData.names;
                year = propleData.years;

                // you can print or save the data to array
            }
```

Comment: `static (string, int) GetNamePeoplesAndYears(string[][] people)

        {
            foreach (var elements in people)
            {
                DateTime bitrthdayElement = ParseDate(elements[2]);
                var yearBirthday = bitrthdayElement.Year;
                var namePeople = elements[1];
            }
            return (namePeople, yearBirthday);

        }`
there is a method that should take all the values from the file, and return the person's year of birth and name

Comment: And your method, which checks this year for leap years and for a difference in years less than 20, I can not connect them in any way

Comment: `static (string,int) NamePeoples(string[][] people)
        {
            string names = null;
            int years = 0;
            foreach (var elements in people)
            {
                DateTime bitrthdayElement = ParseDate(elements[2]);
                var yearBirthday = bitrthdayElement.Year;
                var namePeople = elements[1];
                names = namePeople;
                years = yearBirthday;
            }
            return (names,years);
        }`
This working but return only last result

Comment: can you add the foreach result to a list<someclass> ? and by returning the list you can have all the data you want

Comment: I don't learn a list this my first work

Comment: i changed on `static (string,int) NamePeoples(string[][] people)
        {
            string names = null;
            int years = 0;
            foreach (var elements in people)
            {
                DateTime bitrthdayElement = ParseDate(elements[2]);
                var yearBirthday = bitrthdayElement.Year;
                var namePeople = elements[1];
                names = namePeople;
                years = yearBirthday;
                return (names, years);
            }
            return ("no",0);`
and together i get only a first result

Comment: wait, will change my code. And try that

Comment: @IlyaKvashnin try the code in edit part

Comment: it's quite difficult for me, but now I'll try to figure it out

Comment: ok, go ahead  :)

Comment: okey loop i understand, but can you write more about class? how do it, i this is the first time I come across this

Comment: when i paste you code i have System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TimeTress.Program+propleData] output

Comment: I think, to be honest, that I will not be able to handle further access to these elements, is it possible to somehow write them into an array

Comment: part of code when i get only first or only last result we can't change it for all results?

Comment: can you iterate over the loop and will get an idea of how it works.  If any doubts let me know

Comment: I am literally just learning about loops and this is my lab work.
I can create a new question so that we can figure it out further, now I will try to reformulate the question.
I need to do with a part of mine when, as I said, about displaying only the last, or only the first result, so that this data is written somewhere (I think in a variable) and then I can refer to them, select leap years and display the names of people, which were born in them, I completely forgot about this condition, but if it is possible with your method via list, but it will be more difficult for me

Comment: i create new question and try end it